# Developing Symfony project on external webserver: Best Practices

Tags: symfony, visual-studio-code, ide, webserver

I'm new to Symfony. Most tutorials develop symfony on a local XAMP or MAMP server using Visual Studio Code. It works well because you can edit the PHP files locally, save and check the result. But now I would like to develop on a live (development) server. What is the best way to do this? Can I connect my Visual Studio Code to the live server and work on the machine? Or do I have to download the files from the server first, edit them locally and upload them again?

Comment: You are best off learning Git version control. With Github for example, you can utilise their Actions with a custom script. So you can push changes to your repo and the Action can run a script on your server that pulls any changes. It is a learning curve but also a common workflow.

Comment: U need to set domain dir to public and install symfony apache bundle, Select hosting with ssh support then use git, vendor is heavy weight. Good hostings have instructions for composer installation.

Comment: Sometimes u can have problem with .htaccess or application isolation.